# Interference beetween on my board when shutting down a light on mains supply

Tags: emc

My board is connected to mains supply throught a 220v/12v 15A adapter.
It features 4 stepper drivers L6476, USB / ftdi and ethernet connectivity (wiz850io), microcontroler
is stm32F4.
It's a 4 layers PCB : signal/ground, ground, power supplies, signal/ground.
12v is regulated to 5.5v by LDO and 5.5v to 3.3v by LDO too.

My workbench (so, nothing to do with the board), is lighted by some WS2812/arduino/220V->5v converter bundle.

When I switch off the lights of the bench (basic rocker switch), something happens on the board (reboot or crash).

Unfortunately the board is not at home now and I can't do any measurement for now.
But, I would like to know if it is a recurrent problem, if it is more likely to be something on the power supply or an EMI issue.

Comment: The transient probably finds it way through the power supply through your board through the usb back to earth via the PC. Try connecting the 0V of the psu to mains earth.

Comment: Do the power supplies have mains earth input? Are they connected to earthed mains socket or left unearthed even if they are supposed to be earthed? Do they have isolated/floating output or is the output common lead earthed to mains earth?